# Create EC2 container service instances using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to create a cloudformation template for my ECS cluster so that I can deploy it automatically when needed.
My cluster contains 3 tasks definitions, and 2 instances, and no ECS services.
I created the tasks definitions and the cluster, but I'm stuck in the creation of the EC2 instances. In the  [documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html)
There is only

1. `AWS::ECS::Cluster`,
2. `AWS::ECS::Service` and
3. `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`.

How am I supposed to create the resources of EC2 in the template ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a AWS::ECS::Service declare it as DependsOn a suitable AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup that is declared elsewhere

Or you can make the AWS::ECS::Service depend on a ALB, and the ALB ultimately depends on a AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup

This example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html shows how to use an ALB to do this

Comment: You mean the instances will be created through the Auto Scaling Group ?
so no need to explicitly create them in the template?

Comment: The AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup has a AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration and that contains the AMI identifiers, security groups and other information to actually launch the machines.  Your template needs to contain this

Comment: OK I got you, but my question is, when the instances will be created, will they appear or not in the ECS cluster??

Comment: The instances are created on demand according to the AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget.  See this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/microservice-delivery-with-amazon-ecs-and-application-load-balancers/ for a summary